# class which generates all queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop

I'm creating a class in which MySQL queries will be generated automatically , but I've some problem ...

here is my Database class...

```
 <?php
    class Database {

    var $host="localhost";
    var $username="";    
    Var $password="";
    var $database="";
    var $fr_query;
    var $row= array() ;


public function connect() 
{
    $conn= mysql_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password);
    if(! $conn )
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}

public function db() 
{
    $conn_db = mysql_select_db($this->database);
    if(! $conn_db )
    {
        echo 'Could Not Connect the Database';
    }
}

public function run_query($sql)
{

 $run = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$run)
    {
       throw new Exception("!!!!!Invalid query!!!!!!!"); 
    }

    $newId = mysql_insert_id();

    if($newId)
    {
        return $newId;
    }

    return true;
}


public function fetchRow($fr) 
{
        if($fr)
        {
            $run = mysql_query($fr);
            if($run)
            {
             return mysql_fetch_assoc($run);   
            }
        }
        return null;
}

function fetchAll($fr_query) 
{

        if($fr_query)
        {
        $run = mysql_query($fr_query); 
        if($run)
        {      
            $data=array();
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
            {
                $data[]=$row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
    return null;   
    }
   }   
   $n = new Database();
   $n->connect();
   $n->db();
 ?>
```

and this is my test.php

```
 <?php
  include("database.php");
   class Model_Abstract
  {
   protected $_data  = array();
   protected $_tableName = null;
   protected $_primaryKey = null;

    public function getTableName()
    {                                                    
    return $this->_tableName;
    } 

    public function getPrimaryKey()
    {                                                    
    return $this->_primaryKey;
    }

     public function __set($key, $value = NULL)
     {
     $key = trim($key);
     if(!$key)
     {
        throw new Exception('"$key" should not be empty.');
     }

     $this->_data[$key] = $value;
      return $this;
    }

    public function __get($key)
    {
    $key = trim($key);
    if(!$key)
    {
        throw new Exception('"$key" should not be empty.');
    }

    if(array_key_exists($key, $this->_data))
    {
        return $this->_data[$key];    
    }

    return NULL;
  }

  public function insert()
  {
    print_r($this->_data); 


    $keyString = "`".implode("`,`", array_keys($this->_data))."`";
    $valueString = "'".implode("','", array_keys($this->_data))."'";

    echo $query  = "INSERT INTO `{$this->getTableName()}` ({$keyString}) VALUES ({$valueString})";
    $this->adpater()->run_query($query);

    echo 'Inserted';

}

public function setData($data)
{
    if(!is_array($data))
    {
        throw new Exception('"$data" should not be empty.');    
    }
    $this->_data = $data;
    return $this;
}



public function load($id, $key = null)
{    
    if(!is_int($id) && $id)
    {
        throw new Exception('"$id" should not be blank.');    
    }

    if($id)
    {
       echo $query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->getTableName()}` WHERE `{$this->getPrimaryKey()}` = '{$id}'";
       $data[] = $this->adpater()->fetchRow($query); 


       $tabelName = $this->getTableName();

       foreach($data as &$_data)
       {
           print_r($_data);

           $object = new $tabelName();
           $object->setData($_data);
           $_data = $object;
       }
       print_r($data);
       return $this;
                    /*
       $query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->getTableName()}` WHERE `{$this->getPrimaryKey()}` = '{$id}'";
       $this->_data = $this->adpater()->fetchRow($query); 
       return $this;  */
    }
}


public function loadAll()
{    

       $query = "SELECT * FROM `{$this->getTableName()}`";
       $data[] = $this->adpater()->fetchAll($query); 
       return $data;
    }

public function delete($id, $key = null)
{    
    if(!is_int($id) && $id)
    {
        throw new Exception('"$id" should not be blank.');    
    }

    if($id)
    {
       echo $query = "DELETE FROM `{$this->getTableName()}` WHERE `{$this->getPrimaryKey()}` = '{$id}'";
       $data[] = $this->adpater()->run_query($query); 


       $tabelName = $this->getTableName();

       $msg = 'Deleted Successfully....';
       return $msg;

    }
}

 public function update()
{
    print_r($this->_data); 


    $keyString = "`".implode("`,`", array_keys($this->_data))."`";
    $valueString = "'".implode("','", array_keys($this->_data))."'";

    echo $query  = "UPDATE`{$this->getTableName()}` SET ({$keyString}) = ({$valueString}) WHERE `{$this->getPrimaryKey()}` = '{$id}'";
    $this->adpater()->run_query($query);

    echo 'Updated';

}


   public function adpater()
   {
    return new Database();                      
   }
}

class Product extends Model_Abstract
{
  protected $_tableName = 'product';
  protected $_primaryKey = 'product_id';

}

$product = new Product();

 echo $product->name; 



 $product->insert();

 print_r($product);


$product = new Product();
$product->name = 'Nokia Lumia';
$product->description = 'Windows';
$product->price = '15000';
$product->quantity = '12';
$product->sku = 'x2';
$product->status = '2';
$product->created_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
$product->updated_date = ' ';
?>
```

So in here my problem is in Insert query, the values are same the column_name ...
I'm having Problem in loadAll();
the browser  says "Catchable fatal error:  Object of class Product could not be converted to string in"

Comment: And what do you expect? Maybe it should be `array_keys` for `keyString` and `array_values` for `valueString`?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore because they are deprecated and will be removed in one of the next versions of PHP. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: At valueString i need the value part as an array but its coming as only keys

Comment: You probably want to use `array_values` for your values...

Comment: Otherwise, besides the use of `mysql_` functions, you got the basic idea, although the terms generally used are *create*, *read* (because of [crud](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)) rather than insert, load.

Answer (score 1):

```
$keyString = "`".implode("`,`", array_keys($this->_data))."`";
$valueString = "'".implode("','", array_keys($this->_data))."'";
```

Same lines, same value. Perhaps you meant

```
$keyString = "`".implode("`,`", array_keys($this->_data))."`";
$valueString = "'".implode("','", $this->_data) ."'";
```

Which would take the array keys for `$keyString` and the array values for `$valueString`.

---

**Depreciation warning**

`mysql_*` are deprecated functions. Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/book.pdo.php)

---

**Warning**

This class does **not** protect you against [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection).

Comment: can you guide me for update query also , because in update each column_name follows its value ....???

Comment: INSERT INTO product (`name`,`description`,`price`,`quantity`,`sku`,`status`,`created_date`,`updated_date`) VALUES ('Nokia Lumia','Windows','15000','12','x2','2','0000-00-00 00:00:00',' ')

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '!!!!!Invalid query!!!!!!!' in /var/www/database.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/test.php(56): Database->run_query('INSERT INTO pro...')
#1 /var/www/test.php(204): Model_Abstract->insert()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/database.php on line 36

Comment: @PankajYadav Read your code: this exception is raised because your query returns false. Get the mysql error (using ``mysql[i]_error()`` from http://fr2.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-error.php ) and print it in your ``Exception``. Also, I think you should actually create a dedicated class for that exception instead of using the generic ``Exception`` class.